# Probability that a binomial random variable with $n=10.8\cdot 10^6$ and $p=1.1\cdot 10^{-5}$ is larger than $52$

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Given $n=10.8\cdot 10^{6}$ independent identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables $$X_1,\dots, X_n\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p=11\cdot10^{-6}),$$ what is the following probability? $$\mathsf P \left( X_1 + \cdots + X_n \ge 52 \right)$$

---

#### Motivation

<sub>**Warning:** the following contains material that may cause discomfort to some readers.</sub>

> According to the [United Nations Office on Drugs and Crime 2015 crime statistics](https://knoema.com/UNODCAKRS2015/violent-crime-statistics), the rate of police recorded instances of sexual intercourse without valid consent in Greece in the year 2015 was $1.1$ per $100'000$ people and the population of Greece is around $10.8\cdot 10^6$.

Comment: You could use the normal distribution approach to the binomial distribution.

Comment: Rape is famously underreported in most countries, and I don't see why Greece would be an exception. So whatever you intend to apply this too, you should keep that in mind as to its real world applicability.

Comment: @ThomasAnton No malicious intent in my question. I know rape is famously underreported, I just wanted to calculate this specific probability (there has been a surge of new reports in my country lately and I wanted to know how that deviates from what should be expected).

Comment: You can use a program to compute it.

Comment: @diffset That would be Φ(-52), where Φ(X) is the CDF integral, right?

Comment: You can find the details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation). But since doesn't appear to be a homework question I'll give an answer.

Comment: The opening sentence makes no sense. A random variable taking values where? (maybe subsets of the Greek population?). Likelihood is a concept from statistics to measure goodness of a fit; did you mean probability instead? And if so, probability is associated to an _event_, not to a random variable (certainly not to one taking subsets of a population as values). So what is the distribution of the random variable, and what probability are you talking about?

Comment: Does that $1.1$ out of one hundred thousand apply to the female population only? Anyway, I'm also somewhat uncomfortable having this question here. You could have masked it for a random event?

Comment: This post is being [discussed in meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33956/removing-potentially-unpleasant-flavor-text-from-questions-when-it-has-no-math), where the content was taken to be "flavor text" (made up so as to turn it into a word problem rather than a simple formula application homework problem). It might help if, instead of a disclaimer, you included *context*: that these are real statistics, that you are interested in a real question. You may put a disclaimer/warning as well. Thus clarifying that this isn't a gratuitously upsetting HW problem.

Comment: a quick search on google gave me [this source](https://knoema.com/atlas/Greece/Rape-rate) for the 1.1 number (and now I'm on a list i suppose)

Comment: A "practical" solution could be to use the normal approximation for the binomial distribution $\operatorname{Bin}(n,p) \approx \mathcal N(np, np(1-p))$, and there are lots of calculators/tables for this.

Answer (score 2):

The expected number of occurrences would be $10800000\cdot1.1/100000\approx119$. So having **at least** 52 is very very likey. In fact, R tells me:

```
> binom.test(52,10800000,1.1/100000, alternative="greater")

        Exact binomial test

data:  52 and 10800000
number of successes = 52, number of trials = 10800000, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is greater than 1.1e-05
…
```

Somehow, this is confusing, since you said (before editing your question if I remember correctly) that there has been an increases in the number of occurrences. This scenario suggests that there has actually been a very significant drop:

```
> binom.test(52,10800000,1.1/100000)

        Exact binomial test

data:  52 and 10800000
number of successes = 52, number of trials = 10800000, p-value = 8.528e-12
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 1.1e-05
…
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I obviously undestand that it is very likely, what I wanted to know is the exact probability. Also, I didn't edit the question other than a few syntax errors, so it must have been one of the moderators.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo No worries mate! It is merely the Mathematics of the scenario that I care about. I just thought I should give some context to the question, since it emerged from a real life subject.

Answer (score 2):

I will just focus on the mathematical aspect of the question and not comment on if and how it applies to the real-world question you mentioned above (there are some important issues raised in the comments to your question).

---

The formal question is this: Given $n=10.8\cdot 10^{6}$ identically distributed, independent random variables $$X_1,\dots, X_n\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p=11\cdot10^{-6}),$$ what is $$\mathsf P(X_1+\dots+X_n\ge 52)\text{?}$$

Note that
$$\mathsf P(X_1+\dots+X_n\ge 52)=1-\sum_{k=0}^{51}\mathsf P(X_1+\dots+X_n=k).$$

Since $X_1+\dots+X_n$ has a binomial distribution (cf. [Proof that a sum of Bernoulli rvs has Binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/664011/631742)), $$\mathsf P(X_1+\dots+X_n=k)=\binom nk p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}.$$

A numerical computation gives $$\mathsf P(X_1+\dots+X_n\ge 52)\ge 0.9999999999981=1-1.9 \cdot 10^{-12}.$$

---

If you instead change the formal question to only use half the population, then the computations remained unchanged, except that now $n=5.4\cdot 10^6$, so $$\mathsf P(X_1+\dots+X_n\ge 52)\in[0.847, 0.848].$$

Comment: This was the exact same solution I sketched, but I was unable to find a free online calculator to approximate the aforementioned binomial distribution (more specifically, the finite sum in the RHS). What software did you use for that?

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΚαρλατήρας I used Mathematica (if you want to use Mathematica, a free version is also available with less computational power at https://wolframcloud.com.)

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΚαρλατήρας In fact, you can even do this with WolframAlpha: [click](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BProbability%5BX+%3E%3D+52%2C+X%7EBinomialDistribution%5B54*10%5E5%2C+11*+10%5E-6%5D%5D%5D)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\operatorname E(X)=\operatorname E(X_1+\cdots+X_n) = 118.8$ and this is fairly big, approximating the binomial distribution with normal distribution with the same expected value and the same variance should give good results, provided one bears in mind that the event $\big[X\ge52\big]$ is the same as the event $\big[X>51\big]$ and uses a continuity correction that seeks the probability that the normally distributed random variable is${}>51.5.$

The variance is $npq = (10.8\times10^6\times)\times(11\times10^{-6})\times(1-11\times10^{-6}) = 118.7987. $
$$
\Pr(X>51.5) = \Pr\left(\frac{X - 118.8}{\sqrt{118.7987}} > \frac{51.5-118.8}{\sqrt{118.7987}} \right) = \Pr(Z>-6.1746)
$$
i.e. we seek the probability that a standard normal random variable exceeds a number that is more than six standard deviations below the mean. For all practical purposes that is $1.$

(A crude approximation to the standard deviation is $11.$)

Comment: +1, tangential question: is it easy to estimate the difference (e.g. in probability)? I guess I'm asking for a central limit theorem with rate, my stats is rusty and google is failing me...

Comment: Do you mean the difference between the approximate probability given by the central limit theorem and the exact probability? In a case like this that doesn't seem worth thinking about, but if it had said $111$ instead of $52,$ then I'd have to think about how to estimate that difference, but it would be small. Even when one approximates a Bernoulli distribution, i.e. the distribution of a random variable that is always either $0$ or $1,$ with a normal distribution, when using the continuity correction, the error is never more than about $0.03.$ I found that surprising when I first realized it.

Comment: Yes, and I'm not saying it to cast any doubt over the accuracy of the result, I was just wondering how to prove it. Thanks for the info, that is surprising

Comment: @CalvinKhor : $\qquad \uparrow\qquad$ Now, for example, suppose $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(6,\,0.4)$ and we want $\Pr(X<3).$ the events $[X<3]$ and $[X\le 2]$ are the same, and the continuity correction replaces these with $[X<2.5].$ We have $\operatorname E(X) = 6\times0.4=2.4$ and $\operatorname{var}(X) = 6\times0.4\times(1-0.4) = 1.44.$ We have
$$ \Pr(X<3) = \Pr(X\le2) = \Pr(X<2.5)$$ $$= \Pr\left( \frac{X-2.4}{\sqrt{1.44}} < \frac{2.5-2.4}{1.2}\right)$$ $$ \approx \Pr(Z<0.08333333) \approx 0.5332068 $$ and the exact value is given by$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $$ \Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1) + \Pr(X=2) $$ $$ = 0.6^6 + 6\times0.4\times0.6^5 + 15\times0.4^2\times0.6^4\approx0.54432$$

Comment: @CalvinKhor : So the approximation is not bad even when $n$ is as small as $6. \qquad$

Comment: CalvinKhor : Let $\Phi$ be the c.d.f. of the standard normal distribution. The expectation and st. dev. of $X\sim\operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$ are respectively $p$ and $\sqrt{p(1-p)}.$ $$ \Pr(X=0) = \Pr(X<0.5)$$ $$= \Pr\left( \frac{X-p}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}} < \frac{0.5-p}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}} \right) $$ $$ = \Phi\left( \frac{0.5-p}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}} \right). $$ The largest diffence between $1-p$ (which is the exact probability) and that function of $p$ is about $0.0322.$ That surprised me when I first found it. $\qquad$